# C# Console.Writeline and .Write differences

Tags: c#

I'm just starting to learn C# and I was pointed to Microsoft own dev site for absolute beginner tutorials so I can start learning the proper syntax.

However in the first tutorial challenge they want you to make the console print out

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
```

I tried

```cs
Console.Write("This is the first line.");
Console.WriteLine("This is the second line.");
```

expecting that the second `WriteLine` would trigger a carriage return however it will not start a new line unless I put a

```cs
Console.Writeline(" ");
```

before the first `WriteLine`.

Why would `Console.WriteLine` not trigger the carriage return without first being preceded with a blank `WriteLine`?

much thanks if your willing to help me understand.

Comment: Because it puts a new line after its output, not before. Which is explained in the first sentence of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Also, you can do Console.Writeline(); to output a line terminator, you don't need a string or a string containing a space to write one, and the line terminator depends on the OS, on Windows it is \r\n, so technically you are writing out more than just a carriage return.

Answer (score 3):

```
        Console.Write("A");
        Console.Write("B");
        Console.WriteLine("C");
        Console.WriteLine("D");
        Console.WriteLine("E");
        Console.Write("F");
```

Code from above, would produce output like this:

[image]

That is because, as someone wrote in the comment, WriteLine puts a new line AFTER your output. So, after the Console.WriteLine, there will be a new row.

Answer (score 1):

Console.WriteLine puts a line after the text you write.
if you want to get your result just reverse them.

```
Console.WriteLine("This is the first line.");
Console.Write("This is the second line.");
```

Comment: thank you i noticed if i reversed the code it worked as expected! .WriteLine carriage return AFTER clarifies it ill update my notes.

Comment: More than welcome. Good Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

Because the WriteLine command append the new line after the string inside the " " is writed.

If you add the \n at the end of the string in the Console.Write(), you have the same result.

The \n is a special character that is an alias for write new line command when putted inside a string text.

Console.WriteLine("text") = Console.Write("text\n")